# Why does make use a back quote and single quote around the target name?

Tags: linux, bash, makefile, gnu-make, gnu

I found in all `make` warning / error messages, it uses a single back quote but then a single quote to highlight the user input.

For example, the error message of the undefined makefile name is like

`` Makefile `xxx' was not found. ``

At first I thought it was a typo, but it seems to me it is intended for all messages.

https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Error-Messages.html

It is distinct from the modern development to use both single / double quote around the highlight text, e.g. `Makefile 'xxx' was not found.`

Does anyone know the reason behind it?

Comment: Just to note, this text affectation was changed throughout GNU make over 10 years ago and the changes were released in GNU make 4.0 in 2013.  Modern versions all use `'foo'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess it is a holdover from when fonts were displayed differently. For computer text that was intended to be read by humans, it used to be that (on many systems) using backquote/quote would produce output that resembles the way that English was normally typeset.

Consider for example: https://data.historicaltexts.jisc.ac.uk/view?pubId=bl-001973110&pageId=bl-001973110-660536-22 :

[image]

For other information, see for example:

- discussion of ["backtick-apostrophe" notation](https://world.hey.com/vini/the-weird-backtick-apostrophe-notation-5f3ba4de)
- [Markus Kuhn's explanation](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Emgk25/ucs/quotes.html) of how the X Window System displayed fonts

Comment: and I just found https://english.stackexchange.com/q/17695

Comment: Thanks, especially for the reference of the term `backtick-apostrophe notation'